# How to order factor levels using POSIXct variable?

Tags: r

I have a data set like this

```
library(forcats)
g <- data.frame(var = as.factor(c("C", "B", "A")),
       dt = as.POSIXct(c("2016-01-01 00:02:20","2016-02-01 00:03:43", "2016-03-01 10:00:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC") 
       )
```

I tried to revel the data based on dt field, but I get an error:

```
fct_relevel(g$var, order(g$dt))

> fct_relevel(g$var, order(g$dt))
[1] C B A
Levels: A B C
Warning message:
Unknown levels in `f`: 1, 2, 3 
>
```

How to solve this issue? I would like to use forcats package for this operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can specify the `levels` of 'var' based on the `order` of 'dt'

```
with(g, fct_relevel(var, levels(var)[order(dt)]))
#[1] C B A
#Levels: A B C
```

Based on the example, 'dt' is already `order`ed, so it will not change the `order` of `level`s of 'var'.